# Lingo Filter for Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, lingo

Does anyone know of or have a Lingo filter for Doxygen?

I have played with DocMaker, but it introduces dependencies on director and is not a flexible or full featured as Doxygen.

-Marty

Answer (score 2):

According to [http://www.doxygen.nl](http://www.doxygen.nl/), doxygen is available for:

- C++
- C
- Java
- Objective-C
- Python
- IDL (Corba)
- IDL (Microsoft)
- Fortran
- VHDL
- PHP
- C#
- D (some support)

Sorry, it doesn't look like Lingo is supported.